# What does the SAS '/unique' on a set statement actually do?

Tags: sas

I have some old SAS code to convert into python.

Part of the code does effectively this:

```
data A (index=(key1=(record_id, record_version)));
  set table.xxx (where = ...)
run;

data B;
  set table.yyy (where = ...)
  set A key=key1/unique;
    if _ERROR_ = 1 then do;
      valueA = "";
      _ERROR_ = 0;
    end;
run;
```

I have read the documentation of the [SET and UNIQUE](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=p00hxg3x8lwivcn1f0e9axziw57y.htm&docsetVersion=3.1&locale=en#n0juysmfj4991wn1ljwbrzsscvc6) statements, which says:

> By default, SET begins searching at the top of the index only when the KEY= value changes.
>
> If the KEY= value does not change on successive executions of the SET statement, the search begins by following the most recently retrieved observation. In other words, when consecutive duplicate KEY= values appear, the SET statement attempts a one-to-one match with duplicate indexed values in the data set that is being read. If more consecutive duplicate KEY= values are specified than exist in the data set that is being read, the extra duplicates are treated as not found.
>
> When KEY= is a unique value, only the first attempt to read an observation with that key value succeeds; subsequent attempts to read the observation with that value of the key fail. The *IORC* variable returns a value that corresponds to the SYSRC autocall macro's mnemonic _DSENOM. If you add the /UNIQUE option, subsequent attempts to read the observation with the unique KEY= value succeed. The *IORC* variable returns a 0.

Huh, "subsequent attempts to read the observation with that value of the key fail.". Fail how?

So practically speaking, given A and B are:

```
A record_id record_version valueA     B record_id record_version valueB
  1         1              A11          1         1              B10 
  1         1              A12          1         2              B20
  1         2              A22
  1         3              A33
```

My output will definitely include these rows:

```
record_id record_version valueA valueB
1         1              A11    B10
1         2              A22    B20
```

What I don't understand is what the `if _ERROR_` statement does.

Do I get this?

```
record_id record_version valueA valueB
1         1                     B10
```

Or this?

```
record_id record_version valueA valueB
1         1              A12    B10
```

Do I get this?

```
record_id record_version valueA valueB
1         3              A33    null
```

Or this?

```
record_id record_version valueA valueB
1         3                     null
```

What edge case is the error statement handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is resetting the lookup value to missing when a key from the `set table.yyy (where = ...)` data is NOT present in the lookup table `A`.  If the reset did not occur the lookup value would be what ever value was retrieved from a previous successful lookup.

The `/UNIUE` tells SET that it should retrieve the **first** lookup if there are more than one possible retrievals (i.e. the lookup table A has repeats of record_id/record_version). 
The `_ERROR_` is still needed for resetting the lookup value for the case of no such lookup was found.

The issue really only comes to fore if the master table has a more rows with repeated keys than the non-unique indexed lookup table has repeated keys.

Example:

```
* lookup indexed, but not unique;
* lookup is more typically a 'transaction' table;
data lookup(index=(IDX_key1key2=(key1 key2)));
input key1 key2 valueA $; datalines;
1 1 A11      1st 1 1
1 1 A12      2nd 1 1
1 2 A22
1 3 A33
;

data master;
input key1 key2 valueB $; datalines;
1 1 B10       1st 1 1 
1 2 B20
1 1 B30       1st 1 1 
1 1 B40       2nd 1 1
1 1 B50       3rd 1 1
;

* data for 2nd 1 1 lookup is from 2nd lookup;
* data for 3rd 1 1 lookup is from 2nd lookup and PUT will show _ERROR_=1 in log;
* No _ERROR_ check, that cant be good;
data master_with_keyed_lookup;
  set b;
  set a key=IDX_key1key2;

  put _all_;
run;

* data retrieved for 2nd and 3rd 1 1 lookup are from 1st lookup row due to unique;
* No _ERROR_ check, that cant be good;
data master_with_unique_keyed_lookup;
  set b;
  set a key=IDX_key1key2/unique;

  put _all_;
run;
```

Comment: I see. So am I correct in understanding in my example, the result set would actually just be: (1,1,A11,B10), (1,2,A22,B20), since there are no duplicates for the key in B?

Comment: That is correct.  When you convert to Python you will want to be sure the Python code selects the 'first' lookup and handles 'not found' situations correctly.